# Using a Rc<FnMut> as an FnMut

Tags: rust

Given a `Rc<FnMut>`, how do I use this when mapping over an iterator? For example:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let f = Rc::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(f).collect();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3a3e947872377713364655667ee319ef&version=stable)

Gives the error

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::rc::Rc<[closure@src/main.rs:6:21: 6:26]>: std::ops::FnMut<({integer},)>` is not satisfied
 --> src/main.rs:8:35
  |
8 |     let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(f).collect();
  |                                   ^^^ the trait `std::ops::FnMut<({integer},)>` is not implemented for `std::rc::Rc<[closure@src/main.rs:6:21: 6:26]>`

error[E0599]: no method named `collect` found for type `std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>, std::rc::Rc<[closure@src/main.rs:6:21: 6:26]>>` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:8:42
  |
8 |     let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(f).collect();
  |                                          ^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: the method `collect` exists but the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
          `std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>, std::rc::Rc<[closure@src/main.rs:6:21: 6:26]>> : std::iter::Iterator`
          `&mut std::iter::Map<std::vec::IntoIter<{integer}>, std::rc::Rc<[closure@src/main.rs:6:21: 6:26]>> : std::iter::Iterator`
```

I thought a simple `*f` would fix the problem, but then I get a `cannot move out of borrowed content` error.

The closest I've come is this:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let mut f = Rc::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(Rc::get_mut(&mut f).unwrap()).collect();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=8bfaf1d834a47c82861344a82b7fd321&version=stable)

Comment: You almost *never* want to use `Rc::get_mut` or `Rc::make_mut`.

Comment: `FnMut` requires mutable access; if you need mutable access to a shared value you need a locking concept.  Common patterns are `Rc<RefCell<T>>` and `Arc<Mutex<T>>` - but `FnMut` (and most other traits) won't be implemented automatically because you need to handle lock failures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Passing `f` directly doesn't work, because `Rc<T> where T: FnMut` doesn't implement `FnMut`.

If your closure doesn't perform any mutation (i.e. it implements `Fn`), you can write `&*f` instead. This works because:

1. `Rc` implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.Deref.html), which changes the behavior of the `*` operator such that `*x` expands to `*(x.deref())`, giving us access to the wrapped closure.
2. the `*` operator produces an lvalue, which allows you to take a reference to the result
3. immutable references to types that implement `Fn` [implement](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html#implementors) `FnMut`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let f = Rc::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(&*f).collect();
}
```

However, `&mut *f` won't work if the closure is stored in an `Rc`, because `Rc` doesn't implement `DerefMut`, and thus doesn't let us mutably borrow its interior.

Another option is to pass a closure that calls `f` to `map`.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let f = Rc::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(|v| f(v)).collect();
}
```

[`Deref` coercions are also applied on method calls.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/deref-coercions.html#deref-and-method-calls) Although it doesn't look like one, `f(v)` actually expands (as of Rust 1.23) to `f.call((v,))` (note that this syntax is unstable and thus only a nightly compiler will accept it, if the `fn_traits` feature is enabled).

---

If the closure is in a `Box` instead, then you can write `&mut *f`, because `Box` implements `DerefMut`.

```
fn main() {
    let mut f = Box::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(&mut *f).collect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah! `try_unwrap` will give you move access to the closure, while `*f` will give you a reference to the closure.

So a solution could be:

```
use std::rc::Rc;

fn main() {
    let f = Rc::new(|x| x);
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    match Rc::try_unwrap(f) {
        Ok(f2) => {
            let _: Vec<_> = v.into_iter().map(f2).collect();
        }
        _ => ()
    }
}
```

(Although there's probably a cleaner way to do it)

Comment: You almost *never* want to use `Rc::try_unwrap`; that consumes the `Rc` and only works if there are no other shared owners.

Comment: If you have a single match arm, you can just use `if let`